# Aligning child items in a list of flex parents

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to do a very simple two-column layout that is giving me a hard time. I am still learning the art of flex layout so I'm sure there is something simple that I'm missing. I want a vertical list of `<div>`s, each of which is a flexbox with two child `<div>`s. The width of first child varies based on content. The second child is `flex-grow: 1`, and I want those items to left-align across the set of parents. Instead, the first child is sized to content, and the second butts up against it on the right.

```css
#resultsList {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.result {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.result-text {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="resultsList">
  <div class="result">
    <div class="result-line">Line 147</div>
    <div class="result-text">Blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <div class="result-line">Line 223</div>
    <div class="result-text">Resukt 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <div class="result-line">Line 445</div>
    <div class="result-text">Quick brown fox</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried many combinations of align, justify, etc. but I always get the same (or a worse) result.

Comment: `.rule-result` ?

Comment: Sorry that should be .result, will fix.

Comment: can you show us the intended result?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so:

[I think is this what you mean right?](https://codepen.io/broderickdevelopment/pen/aaggOY)

There's a lot of flex going on here so the basic principles are:

- `main-container` holds everything, displaying it as `flex`. Fixed width of `600px`.
- `sub-container` is each flex item, being display as `column`.
- `first-container` is a fixed width (in this case: `150px`) and `flex-grow: 1;`
- `content` does not have a flex grow property, and so is only the width of its content.
- `padder` has a `flex-grow` property, so it will take up the rest of the remaining space.
- `second-container` takes up the rest of the container.

The rest is just the use of borders. Where applicable you can make `border-{top|bottom|left|right}` to none, so it appears as if the box is extended out. Try using the chrome dev tools to see the width of each component.

```css
.main-container {
  width: 600px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.sub-container {
 display: flex;
}

.first-container {
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-right: none;
 flex-grow: 1;
 display: flex;
 max-width: 150px;
}

.content {
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 padding: 10px;
}

.padder {
 flex-grow: 1;
}

.second-container {
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-left: none;
 flex-grow: 2;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main-container">

  <div class="sub-container">
   <div class="first-container">
    <div class="content">
     <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="padder"></div>

   </div>
   <div class="second-container">
    <p>text</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
   <div class="first-container">
    <div class="content">
     <p>sample text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="padder"></div>

   </div>
   <div class="second-container">
    <p>text</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
   <div class="first-container">
    <div class="content">
     <p>more sample text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="padder"></div>

   </div>
   <div class="second-container">
    <p>text</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't post another answer, either delete the other one or edit it

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, but I can't be guessing at the max-width of the first child, which is necessary in your solution.